# jQuery Tooltip in IE6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, jquery-tooltip

I'm currently fighting with the jQuery Tools Tooltip. It works as claimed in IE8/Firefox, but the client also needs it to work in IE6. From everything I saw on their site, as well as the fact that it works elsewhere in the project, I know it is compatible with IE6.

I believe the hang-up is coming on the fact that I am attaching the tooltip to an AJAX generated list of table rows. I have thus far attempted this two ways, both of which seem to work in IE8/Firefox, neither of which work in IE6.

Attempt 1:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
                // get the undeclared additions and populate the table
                $.getJSON("/Drm/Pc/GetUndeclaredAssistanceRecords?partnumber=<%= Model.PartNumber %>",
                function(data) {
                    var rowEntry = "";
                    var rowClass = "odd";
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                        // Fix for Bug 71 starts
                        strComment = "";
                        for (var k = 0; k < data[i].Comment.length; k++) {
                            if (data[i].Comment.substring(k, k + 1) == "'")
                                strComment = strComment + "";
                            else
                                strComment = strComment + data[i].Comment.substring(k, k + 1);
                        }

                        strComment = strComment.replace(";", ",");
                        strComment = strComment.substring(0, 400);

                        var rowEntry = "<tr class='" + rowClass + "'><td class='pcassistresultsCenterAlign'>" + data[i].PurchaseOrder + "</td><td class='pcassistresultsLeftAlign'>" + data[i].SupplierName + "</td><td class='pcassistresultsCenterAlign'>" + data[i].Amount + "<td class='pcassistresultsCenterAlign'>" + data[i].RecordType + "</td></tr>";
                        rowEntry = rowEntry + "<tr class='" + rowClass + "'><td class='pcassistresultsDetailTitle'>Shipment Date:</td><td>" + data[i].ShipDate + "</td><td class='pcassistresultsDetailTitle'>Input On:</td><td class='pcassistresultsDetailData'>" + data[i].InputOn + "</td></tr>";
                        rowEntry = rowEntry + "<tr class='" + rowClass + "'><td class='pcassistresultsDetailTitle'>Req Recon:</td><td class='pcassistresultsDetailData'>" + data[i].ReqRecon + "</td><td class='pcassistresultsDetailTitle'>Input By:</td><td class='pcassistresultsDetailData'>" + data[i].InputBy + "</td></tr>";
                        rowEntry = rowEntry + "<tr class='" + rowClass + "'><td class='pcassistresultsDetailTitle'>From Site</td><td class='pcassistresultsDetailData'>" + data[i].FromSite + "</td><td class='pcassistresultsDetailTitle'>Input By Phone:</td><td class='pcassistresultsDetailData'>" + data[i].InputByPhone
                        rowEntry = rowEntry + "<tr class='" + rowClass + "'><td class='pcassistresultsDetailTitle' valign='top'>Comment:</td><td colspan='3' rowspan='2' title='" + strComment + "' ><div style='overflow:hidden; height:30px;'>" + data[i].Comment + "</div></td></tr>";


                        rowEntry = rowEntry + "<tr class='" + rowClass + "'><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";

                        //Fix for Bug 71 ends

                        $('#unDecAddTable tbody>tr:last').after(rowEntry);
                        rowClass = rowClass == 'odd' ? 'even' : 'odd';
                        }
                        $('#unDeclaredAdditions *').tooltip();
                });
            });
```

Attempt 2 is the same as above, but with the .tooltip() piece removed and the following code added outside the document.ready function

```
        function PinTooltips() {
            $('#unDeclaredAdditions *').tooltip();
            $('#declaredAdditions *').tooltip();
        }
        $('#declaredAdditions').ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
            PinTooltips();
        });
```

Does anyone see where I went wrong or know something unusual about IE6 that would inhibit this from working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem...and this is weird.
Elsewhere in the project, it was assigning tooltips to a very large span of fields. In every browser except IE6, it was not assigning said tooltip to the comments td like I needed it to. But for some reason, in IE6, it was. So, when I tried to call the .tooltip() again it was breaking. As a result, I ended up putting in code to check for the browser being IE6. If it was IE6, don't try to re-attach the tooltip.

Very strange and I have no idea why it works that way, but that was my solution.